# pyspark using agg to concat string after groupBy

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

In pandas dataframe, I am able to do

```
df2 = df.groupBy('name').agg({'id': 'first', 'grocery': ','.join})
```

from

```
name        id        grocery
Mike        01        Apple
Mike        01        Orange
Kate        99        Beef
Kate        99        Wine
```

to

```
name        id        grocery
Mike        01        Apple,Orange
Kate        99        Beef,Wine
```

since id is the same across multiple rows for the same person, I just took the first one for each person, and concat the grocery.

I can't seem to make this work in pyspark. How can I do the same thing in pyspark? I want the grocery to be string instead of list

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `collect_list` to collect elements into a list and then join the list as string with `concat_ws`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

df.groupBy("name")
  .agg(
      f.first("id").alias("id"), 
      f.concat_ws(",", f.collect_list("grocery")).alias("grocery")
   ).show()

#+----+---+------------+
#|name| id|     grocery|
#+----+---+------------+
#|Kate| 99|   Beef,Wine|
#|Mike| 01|Apple,Orange|
#+----+---+------------+
```